# font style order in canvas drawText

Tags: css, html

If I draw a text on a canvas and set the font property the text is not show
correctly if I change the order of values into the string property:

This work right:

```
context.font = "italic bold 24px Verdana"
```

but this not:

```
context.font = "bold Verdana italic 24px"
```

Into specification is asserted that this rules is the same as CSS rules but
If I put also font-variant and line-height it does not work:

Into CSS rules the order is as follow?

**style variant weight size line-hieght family**

Answer (score 2):

The 'font' property values need to be put in a specific order as described by the CSS 2.1 specifiation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-shorthand

Also note that the HTML5 specification says that any setting of line-height (while allowed) will be ignored.